# Visual Studio: Include .h or .cpp in two-project solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include, projects-and-solutions

I have a Visual Studio solution containing 2 project: main project and test (via googletest). In main project I have myclass.cpp and myclass.h files. When I'm trying to compile test project, there are bunch of LNK2019 errors when I include "myclass.h" in my test.cpp file, but everything works fine if I include "myclass.cpp" instead. Is that normal? As far as I know, including of .cpp files is not recommended and generally can be avoided. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your main.cpp should be in the same project.
Are you using precompiled headers?

Comment: Actually, I want to have 2 main functions and generate 2 .exe files - one for my programm, one for test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal. If you have 2 projects, 2 binaries will be generated.

**Don't include the cpp file**.

Instead, link the binaries together.

**main project** - generates `.lib` file and either `.dll` or `.exe`.

**test project** - includes header from `main`. You need to add the `.lib` generated by main in the additional dependencies of the test project. Somewhere in the Project Settings - Linker Options - Additional Dependencies.

---

You can generate *both* .exe and .lib file from a single project. To do this you set:

- **exe** in `Linker -> General -> Output File`
- **lib** in `Linker -> Advanced -> Import Library`

You may also need to mark exported functions with `__declspec( dllexport )` in the .exe project (see [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3y1sfaz2.aspx)), otherwise compiler won't generate a .lib file.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I have another question - can I generate both .exe and .lib files for my main project? As far as I've found out, generated file is specified in configuration properties, and only one type of file can be specified.

Comment: @YuriyPogrebnyak yes you can. You specify the exe in `Linker -> General -> Output File` and the lib in `Linker -> Advanced -> Import Library`

Comment: Is this lib file a static lib or import library?  What if the test project would like to call functions and use classes that are not exported from the DLL?

Answer (score 1):

**Steps to Use Classes form another project (Add header and solver linker errors)**

1) To be able to add the header from another project, first go to *"Properties > c++ > General > Additional Include Directories"* and add the directory that contains the header. Now you will be able to add the header of the class from the other project, but running the project will still cause Linker Errors.

2) Add _*_declspec(dllexport)* before the class you are using for the other project. This can be added in the header file of that class. This should be added right before the function or variable or class name. Now you will get a lib file. (if placed in wrong place, you can get this warning: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehkcz60.aspx)

3) *"Properties > Linker > Additional Library Directories"*. Specify the location of the lib file that is generated.

4) *"Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies”*: Add the name of the lib file.